# Existence of a certain diffeomorphism $f$ of $\mathbb R^n$ s.t. $f^{*}\omega_0=\omega_0$, $\omega_{0}$ is the standard volume form on $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms, pullback

Consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard volume form $\omega_{0}:=dx_1\wedge ...\wedge dx_n$ .  Let $r$ and $R$ be two positive real numbers, with $R > r$ .  Show that for every $a, b \in B (0, r )$, there exists a diffeomorphism $f$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(a) = b , f(x)= x$ for $|| x || > R$ and $f ^{*}\omega_{0} = \omega_{0}$.

One-dimensional case is fine. I have tried to extend that idea to the higher dimensional case. I have an exam. I don't understand how to construct $f$. Hints are welcomed. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: When you write, "I have an exam", do you mean this question is an exam question?

Comment: It's a potential problem for the exam.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$**Hint**: Let $(r, \theta)$ denote polar coordinates on $\Reals^{2}$. If $\phi:(0, \infty) \to \Reals$ is an arbitrary smooth function, the formula
$$
f(r, \theta) = \bigl(r, \theta + \phi(r)\bigr)
$$
defines a "rotational shear" mapping that is smooth and area-preserving.

Comment: If $b=(r_1,\phi), a=(r,\phi_1)$, then $f(a) \neq b$,as $f$ preserves the distance from origin.Then how should I use this function?

Comment: You might put the origin of your polar coordinate system at the midpoint $O = \frac{1}{2}(a + b)$, for example.